# How to name the column that contains integer number for sorting?

Tags: database

I don't know how to name this column because my english is bad. Now, I name it "sorting", is it correct?

```
| id | name | sorting |
-----------------------
| 1  | foo  |    0    | 
| 2  | bar  |    1    |
```

Comment: I would use `order` personally, but `sorting` would probably be ok too.  That said, this question seems off topic and will probably be closed.

Comment: Agree w/ Abe: `sort_order` or `sorting_order` to be most clear.

Comment: This question would be best asked (including an explanation of the purpose of the column) on [English.SE].

Comment: @AbeMiessler: `order` is not such a good idea because it is a reserved word

Comment: +1, That's a really good point.  It could still work but it would require extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is fine.

You could also have:

- ordering;
- <s>order</s>;
- ranking;
- sort_order;
- sorting_order.

As pointed out in the comments, *order* should not really be used "as it is a reserved keyword and will require the use of a quoted identifier (or sometimes referred to as "delimited" identifier)"

Comment: `order` is not such a good idea as it is a reserved keyword and will require the use of a quoted identifier (or sometimes referred to as "delimited" identifier)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a page from Joe Celko's excellent [SQL Programming Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120887975). Section 1.2.4 takes you through developing standardized postfixes. In your case, the following excerpt applies:

> “_seq” = sequence, ordinal numbering. This is not the same thing as a
>   tag number, because it cannot have gaps.

So something like `sort_seq` or `sorting_seq` could apply here.

Answer (score 1):

If it is hard for you to come up with english names use your native language. There is nothing wrong with it.